# Create hidden input for each checkbox that is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a hidden input inside of a form for each row that is checked and I want to insert the value of each hidden input with the ids that are from a hidden column.

Here is what i have so far:

```
.on('check.bs.table check-all.bs.table', function (row) {           
        var selects = $('#users-table').bootstrapTable('getSelections');
            ids = $.map(selects, function (row) {
                return row.id;                          
            });                 
                    var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');           
            input.setAttribute('name', 'delete['+ids+']');
            input.setAttribute("id", 'delete['+ids+']');            
            input.setAttribute('value', 'delete['+ids+']');         
            //append to form element that you want .
            document.getElementById("deleteModalForm").appendChild(input);  
        })
```

It is creating a new hidden input for each box that is checked like I want it to, but the problem I am having is that it is joining the ids together. Here is an example of whats happening:

```
<input value="delete[3]" id="delete[3]" name="delete[3]" type="hidden">
<input value="delete[3,2]" id="delete[3,2]" name="delete[3,2]" type="hidden">
```

What i want it to do is this:

```
<input value="delete[3]" id="delete[3]" name="delete[3]" type="hidden">
<input value="delete[2]" id="delete[2]" name="delete[2]" type="hidden">
```

If it helps I am using [Bootstrap Data Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)

Can someone please help me with this?

EDIT: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikev10/e3nk137y/707/). As you check the box it will add a new input and you will see that each input joins the numbers. For this example I did not use `type="hidden"`

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or something?

Comment: See the working code below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `row.stargazers_count` directly?

`row` is an object of currently selected row, `row.stargazers_count` represents row value of `data-field='stargazers_count'` column.

```
input.setAttribute('value', 'delete['+row.stargazers_count+']');
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/L3ut9bhs/)

`getSelections` do the same job but it takes **all** selected rows into object, so that you have to extract the last one :

```
var selects = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections');
var stars   = selects[selects.length-1].stargazers_count;
input.setAttribute('value', 'delete['+stars+']');
```

But it's unnecessary operation on array, since you have a `row` right on your hand, and for that purposes you're passing it to the event:

```
.on('check.bs.table', function (e, /* here it is: */ row){
```

---

You have more problems with your code:

- This ain't gonna work, as you repeating inputs names:

  ```
  input.setAttribute('name', 'delete['+row.stargazers_count+']');
  ```

  use this instead, it will create array of names automatically on submit:

  ```
  input.setAttribute('name', 'delete[]');
  ```
- This ain't gonna work also, because you repeating inputs id (they have to be unique):

  ```
  input.setAttribute("id", 'delete['+row.stargazers_count+']');
  ```

  use `row.id` instead:

  ```
  input.setAttribute("id", 'delete_'+row.id);
  ```

---

Why it is joining the ids together?

> `.map()` Translate all items in an array or object **to new array of items**.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Comment: Thanks. Although this works in the demo it does not work for me when i add it to my code.

Comment: @iamthestreets , what do you mean *not works*? I cannot find anything why it would't work. With `.map()` you're making unnecessary calculations for selecting rows. You need the `.map()` to gather the rows for deletion, not for selecting rows. You have actually 2 other problems with your code (inputs `id` and `name`)... See: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cL79L6d3/)

Answer (score 1):

I took the top most `star` using `stars.pop()`

**Updated Code**

```
 .on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
        var selects = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections');
            stars = $.map(selects, function (row) {
                return row.stargazers_count;                          
            }); 
            stars = stars.pop();
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');           
            input.setAttribute('name', 'delete['+stars+']');
            input.setAttribute("id", 'delete['+stars+']');            
            input.setAttribute('value', 'delete['+stars+']');         
            //append to form element that you want .
            document.getElementById("deleteModalForm").appendChild(input);  
        $result.text('Event: check.bs.table');
    })
```

**Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/e3nk137y/711/)**

Comment: Thanks this worked! In the demo you will notice there is a section for ` .on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row)` do you know how i can remove the input after i uncheck each box?